# Application "stops working" on OneClick installation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

newbie here,
VB.NET app on a Win7 32 bit machine.  .NET 4.0 loaded on the machine, VB app published with .NET target 3.5.

VS2008 OneClick deployed as Available Online only.

Application runs fine using an administrator's UID on the machine but as a standard user OneClick sends a "(program name) has stopped working" message box with "Check Online... " and "Close the Program" options.

Seems to be a permissions issue but would appreciate any ideas on how to trap the problem area?  How can I find out what it's trying to load to the local machine (and where) that it doesn't have permissions for?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Make sure the assembly is signed ??? Doesn't have to be signed with a password. UAC will cause issues if you try to write anything to the Program/Program(x86) directories, I believe.

Comment: |Abstract... thanks for the response.  Yes the assembly is signed.  I did find a great code segment that captured more details of the error.  It turned out to be a simple DB authentication issue.